# How to assign value of type NSURL to type UIimage?

Tags: json, swift, uiimage, nsurl

Hello I have a Json file:

```
{
   "Name":"Car",
   "Picture":"http://www.starpropertiesindia.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/kochi1.jpg",
   "Description":"Ford"
}
```

which reads name picture and description in a Table View Controller.

I have this code in my TableViewController:

```
let name = aFruit["Name"].stringValue
let imageURL = aFruit["Picture"].stringValue
let description = aFruit["Description"].stringValue
```

and Now I want to return them into the Table View Cells. For this case I use this code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as!  TableViewCell
    let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]
    cell.CellTitle.text = fruit.name
    cell.CellDescription.text = fruit.description
    cell.CellImage.image = fruit.imageURL
    return cell
}
```

Everything works perfect for

```
cell.CellTitle.text = fruit.name
```

and

```
cell.CellDescription.text = fruit.description
```

But when I write

```
cell.CellImage.image = fruit.imageURL
```

It gives me an error:

> Cannot  assign value of type NSURL to type UIimage !

What might be the mistake here?

Comment: where is your network call to get the image?

Comment: The error clearly states, .image expects UIImage instance not the URL ... U can call asynchronous request for lazy loading of images  ...

Comment: Would you please show me an example I am a beginner and I do not undestand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this... I haven't tested this.

```
let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: fruit.imageURL)))
```

Comment: @Dakata "not working" isn't a good description when you are programming... Are you getting errors or crashes? Please be more specific.